# How does generation 0 and 1 collection work?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I know that when an object survives a generation cleanup it moves onto the next. I also know that generation 2 cleanup is a stop the world thing.

My question is how does it know what memory to check for the generation cleanup? Is generation 0 a codeblock and in its case it checks all objects access in that block? If so then when/where does generation 1 happen?

Comment: Note that this question depends a bit on which GC: server? desktop? concurrent? server-background (in .NET 4.5)? or... on full MS.NET? Mono? MonoDroid? MonoTouch? CF? XNA? MF? SL? WP7 (all of which have very different GC)

Comment: @MarcGravell What what? Server-background? Where where? Is there an article?

Comment: @xanatos http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/17/improvements-in-the-clr-core-in-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks... I had just found it... This evening I'll watch the Maoni Stephens' video.

Comment: They are separate heaps under the hood.  You got the 'stop the world' backwards, it stops for gen 0 and 1 collections.  Gen 2 is concurrent on workstation GC.  And server in 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to check out Jeffrey Richter's original memory management garbage collection articles for this.

[Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

[Garbage Collection Part 2: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)